# How can I show that $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are identically distributed (ID) random variables?

Tags: probability

Suppose an urn contains 1 red ball and 2 white balls. A person draws out balls, one at a
time and without replacement.

Let $X_i=1$, if the ith ball is red, and $0$ otherwise.

How can I show that $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are identically distributed (ID) random variables?

To show ID, do I need to calculate their joint probabilities?

Comment: This seems like something that one can assume and not have to calculate.

Comment: Identically distributed means they have the same cdf. One sufficient condition is that the pmf of all three are the same. So calculate and show that $P(X_{1}=1)=P(X_{2}=1)=P(X_{3}=1)$ and also $P(X_{1}=0)=P(X_{2}=0)=P(X_{3}=0)$

Answer (score 1):

You need to find pmf for each of your random variables. And you will see that they are identical

Comment: Nice,short and to the point. Welcome to MSE.